# How to set a Color from resources?

Tags: android, colors, android-resources

when changing TextView color programmatically from my own color.xml it doesn't give me the real color but if I use the android colors it will work fine

for example

```
android color: textview.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
android color: textview.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
android color: textview.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Android Colors will give the same colors

```
my own color: textview.setTextColor(color.maroon); color code(#800000)
my own color: textview.setTextColor(color.MistyRose); color code(#FFE4E1)
my own color: textview.setTextColor(color.OldLace); color code(#FDF5E6)
```

my own colors will give another colors

any help??

Comment: can u publish the color.xml code

Comment: Color.onecolor is your color not android, to get android's use R.color.white

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

`textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.some_color));`